# Jquery getJSON not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-chrome, xampp

I am trying to read local json file using getJSON method of jquery, So I write following code to read, but console log is working fine in firefox and showing output but not working in chrome. 
on chrome I got this error:

```
Request Failed: parsererror, SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 951
```

here is code which I write:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

        $.getJSON('http://localhost/page2/data/cd.json',function(data){
          alert("success");
          console.log(data);
      })
        .fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
            var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
            console.log( "Request Failed: " + err );
        });



    });
```

I hosted this file in Xampp local server,
I also check JSON file for validation.
The file is valid JSON file.

Comment: can you confirm your json is a valid one like `{"key":"value"}`

Comment: I am not sure, how did you validated your json, but could you please check it on http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: yes file is vaildate using jsonlint.com

Answer (score 0):

guys, I got something strange, 
here is my json file

```
{
    "country": {
        "city": {
            "1": "A",
            "2": "B"
        },
        "cars": {

        }
    }
}
```

here car segment does not have any value so I keep it empty when I checked this on  JSONLint.com it says it's valid JSON. and firefox also not show any error but chrome does. so I make add new key value into the cars like following.

```
{
    "country": {
        "city": {
            "1": "A",
            "2": "B"
        },
        "cars": {
            "1": "none"
        }
    }
}
```

and its start working in chrome. Can anyone explain Why its invalid into chrome? but valid into firefox.

Answer (score 0):

There must be issue in JSON please validate your JSON data on https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Best luck

Answer (score 0):

Your test json data works fine with chrome, after remove all "carriage return" 
You can test it with JSON.parse('{"country": {"city": { "1": "A", "2": "B" }, "cars": {} }}'); in chrome console.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFDGU.png)

According [spec](http://www.json.org/), it allows use empty object as a value.
Thanks,
Yong

Comment: If your data is sensitive, you can use this JSON validator: http://www.datatoolkits.com/json/validation.html , it validates JSON data at your browser side.